# WatchKit app hangs & crashes via Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crash, watchkit, freeze, crashlytics

**Setup:**

- Xcode 6.3.2
- iOS/WatchKit SDK 8.3

**What Works:**

- App groups are configured and tested to be working.
- Local development builds with development provisioning profiles work.
- I can build & debug to my Apple Watch hardware.
- Simulator also works (not that this matters).

Now, enter ad hoc distributions via Crashlytic using our CI (Jenkins) environment. The application is distributed fine, and installs on device fine.

But....

**Issue:**

- Launching the application once installed on the Watch (via Crashlytics) results in a spinner that hangs forvever.
- Eventually (after about a minute) the app crashes.
- I've stripped the application down to a single controller with a button (no networking or heavy async stuff going on).

To re-iterate - my local development builds to device work perfectly fine.

Any ideas!? Is there a way to get the logs for what is going on with the watch?

Comment: The plot thickens!
 
We re-genereated all of our certificates to ensure they were swift compliant.
 
Now we have a new error:
 
Program specified by service does not contain one of the requested architectures: 16777228:arm64  
 
We have triple checked that both the parent app, extension and all linked frames are arm64 compliant (via "Archictures -> Standard Architectures").
 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

For anyone interested, we accidently had left a ARCHS='armv7' argument in our xcodebuild script.

Comment: Can u please provide details, I am facing same issue with WatchOS2